# Can using dummy variable be counted as using time fixed effect or or year effect?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, meta-analysis, fixed-effects-model, time-varying-covariate

I am currently using 2 dummy variables:

-A dummy variable 'Crisis' which captures the effects of the Great Recession of 2007–2009 and COVID-19 (and takes a value of 1 for the years 2009 and 2020 and zero otherwise)

-Another dummy variable 'Reporting' which is to account for the changes in new ESG directive in 2014(and takes a value of 1 for the years 2014-2021 considering post-rule changes and zero otherwise)

I wanted to know if this can be called as using time fixed effect? I'm not using i.year as it gives results that aren't valid- I'm thinking that using i.year is often called as year effect? I'm new to regression modelling, so wanted to know if it is wrong to say I have controlled for year effect by using dummy variables, when not using i.year

Any input is highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.